# Calculate datetime difference in C

Tags: c, datetime, struct

I need a function that can calculate the difference between two datetime (year, month, day, hours, minute, seconds). and then return the difference in the same format.

```
int main (){

    struct datetime dt_from;
    init_datetime(&dt_from, 1995, 9, 15, 10, 40, 15);

    struct datetime dt_to;
    init_datetime(&dt_to, 2004, 6, 15, 10, 40, 20);

    struct datetime dt_res;

    datetime_diff(&dt_from, &dt_to, &dt_res);

    return 0;

}

void datetime_diff(struct datetime *dt_from, struct datetime *dt_to
, struct datetime *dt_res) {

    //What can I do here to calculate the difference, and get it in the dt_res?

}
```

Comment: You mean something like the standard [`difftime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/difftime) function?

Comment: struct datetime is not portable. You should use "time.h" library, therefore you should use struct tm

Comment: 1) Post definition of `struct datetime`.  2) Post definition of `init_datetime()()`  3) Describe how code should handle overflows would be useful.  (max time - min time)

Comment: Question: what difference value do you expect on the date where daylight saving time switches from summer time to winter time with `dt_from` at 1:50 AM and `dt_to` at 3:50 AM? Or more generally: do you require culture and region aware arithmetics?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look and try this example which uses `time.h` and should be portable. It calculates the difference in days between the dates in your question. You can change the program a little so that it works the way you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    time_t start_daylight, start_standard, end_daylight, end_standard;;
    struct tm start_date = {0};
    struct tm end_date = {0};
    double diff;

    printf("Start date: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &start_date.tm_mday, &start_date.tm_mon, &start_date.tm_year);
    printf("End date: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &end_date.tm_mday, &end_date.tm_mon, &end_date.tm_year);

    /* first with standard time */
    start_date.tm_isdst = 0;
    end_date.tm_isdst = 0;
    start_standard = mktime(&start_date);
    end_standard = mktime(&end_date);
    diff = difftime(end_standard, start_standard);

    printf("%.0f days difference\n", round(diff / (60.0 * 60 * 24)));

    /* now with daylight time */
    start_date.tm_isdst = 1;
    end_date.tm_isdst = 1;
    start_daylight = mktime(&start_date);
    end_daylight = mktime(&end_date);
    diff = difftime(end_daylight, start_daylight);

    printf("%.0f days difference\n", round(diff / (60.0 * 60 * 24)));

    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
Start date: 15 9 1995
End date: 15 6 2004
3195 days difference
```

Or even simpler for non-interactive code and with standard or daylight savings time:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    time_t start_daylight, start_standard, end_daylight, end_standard;;
    struct tm start_date = {0};
    struct tm end_date = {0};
    double diff;

    start_date.tm_year = 1995;
    start_date.tm_mon = 9;
    start_date.tm_mday = 15;
    start_date.tm_hour = 10;
    start_date.tm_min = 40;
    start_date.tm_sec = 15;

    end_date.tm_mday = 15;
    end_date.tm_mon = 6;
    end_date.tm_year = 2004;
    end_date.tm_hour = 10;
    end_date.tm_min = 40;
    end_date.tm_sec = 20;

    /* first with standard time */
    start_date.tm_isdst = 0;
    end_date.tm_isdst = 0;
    start_standard = mktime(&start_date);
    end_standard = mktime(&end_date);
    diff = difftime(end_standard, start_standard);

    printf("%.0f days difference\n", round(diff / (60.0 * 60 * 24)));

    /* now with daylight time */
    start_date.tm_isdst = 1;
    end_date.tm_isdst = 1;
    start_daylight = mktime(&start_date);
    end_daylight = mktime(&end_date);
    diff = difftime(end_daylight, start_daylight);

    printf("%.0f days difference\n", round(diff / (60.0 * 60 * 24)));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code has Undefined Behavior on invalid user input. That is generally a bad thing in any example code, which people might copy.

Comment: `mktime()` reads all fields of `struct tm` except `tm_yday, tm_wday`.  This code only sets 6 of them - missing others.  Suggest initializing with `struct tm start_date = {0};` to set all fields and research `tm_isdst`.

Comment: Adding 0.5 is problematic for rounding.  No need to limit answer to `int` range.  Recommend  `printf("%.0f days difference\n", round(seconds / (60.0 * 60 * 24)));`

Comment: @chux I tried to improve my answer. Would you please have a look again if it is better? Thanks for the advice

Comment: Good improvement.  The typical assignment is `tm_isdst = -1` as in "let mktime()" figure it out for one time-stamp may be in daylight time and the other not so.  The typical problem is that 1 hour per year when a time-stamp could be valid as daylight or not.  OP's has not, sigh, posted the details of `struct datetime` which may guide the answer.

Comment: BTW Code _certainly_ should be `start_date.tm_year = 1995-1900;
    start_date.tm_mon = 9-1;`  See docs on `struct tm` for details.

Comment: Further: `mktime()` adjusts all its fields to their primary range upon completion.  So re-using  `start_date` in the 2nd `mktime()`, _in general_, may have the same field values that you started with in the first call of `gmtime()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic idea:

Convert your `datetime` into an integral type (preferable `long long` or `unsigned long long`) which represents your `datetime` value as it's smallest unit (second in your case). How to achieve that? Easy transform the single values into seconds and add everything together. (`seconds + minutes * 60 + hours * 3600 ...`)

Do this for both values and then subtract the integer values.

Now convert the single integer value, the time difference, back to a `datetime`. How? Start with the biggest unit (years) and divide the difference by the amount of seconds within one year (60 * 60 * 24 * 365). Now you know how many years are in between your two `datetime`s. Take the rest and divide it by the amount of seconds per month, and so on...

(Obviously I ignored everything rather complicated, like daylight saving time for example)

---

However I would highly recommend using `struct tm` from `time.h` as mentioned in the comments. It is portable and you can use `difftime`.