# Integer comparisons in c

Tags: c

When I'm comparing my month variable(inputed from user), I want to use it to get another. The way I'm doing this is saying if `if(1 < m <= 3) { x = 1 }`, and it doesn't let me because "comparison of three boolean expressions is always true. I need this variable to be integrated into an equation so I can calculate the thing I need to calculate, and is dependent on the user input. How do I fix this?

Comment: "The way I'm doing this is ..." please provide a [mre] of that.

Answer (score 0):

This does not exist in most programming languages:

```
1 < m <= 3
```

You need to translated into something like:

```
(1 < m) AND (m <= 3)
```

Which, in C, is best written as:

```
(1 < m) && (m <= 3)
```

Comment: *This does not exist in programming languages:*  It certainly does in [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).  And probably others.

Comment: well I'm doing an age calculator in c as a final project for a course I'm taking and I'm using a formula to find how many days are in the year thus far for another formula im using. Since 30 is a constant in this case, I need to add in the months with 31 days, and to to do that, I'm cumulating the amount of months there are with 31 days before the expressed date, and adding in the extra days that come from those months. to do that, I need this. Is there any way I can do that with C?

Comment: @Relativity1395: I know that, in Excel, in order to know the number of today can be calculated as `DATEVALUE("22/6/2022")-DATEVALUE("01/01/2022")+1`, maybe a similar thing exists in C?

Comment: @Relativity1395: there are other StackOverflow posts about working with datetime entries in C, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489260/calculate-datetime-difference-in-c